# Store image in AWS s3 bucket and then the resulted url in database

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am able to store image in s3 bucket from android.Now when I store image in the bucket , I want to store the download url of the image in database table. How to get the download url of the image as soon as I stored it in bucket?

Comment: Do you mean a signed URL one or public one?

Comment: Either is fine. But it would be good for signedUrl

Answer (score 5):

You should store the Object Key in DB. You specify a key while storing the object in S3, and then go ahead and store this in the DB. From this key the download URL can be constructed.

Object Key and Metadata - Amazon Simple Storage Service : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html